# Why server side geo location detection is preferred over client side API call?

Tags: server, client, google-tag-manager, ip-geolocation

I need to implement geo location detection on our website. 
(I need to calculate and pass state variable to Google Tag Manager, in future this variable might be used on server side to render specific block depending on state, but for now it will be only needed in client side for GTM)

I've found [this article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/send-weather-data-to-google-analytics-in-gtm-v2/) very helpful. It's a bit more complex example for detecting weather. I need only geo location.
In the article the author gives example with client side API call, but several times he recommends using exactly server-side calls.

> For those who want to take this weather analysis seriously, I really
>   recommend moving to a 100% server-side solution, where the weather
>   data is polled before the page itself is rendered, and the data is
>   written in the dataLayer of the page.

and

> If you’re serious about this solution, you might want to install a
>   geolocation service on your own web server, so that you’ll avoid
>   needing to make any extra API calls in the client.

So seems like server-side detection is better, but I don't really understand why. Could anyone explain please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One given reason is security - if you query a commercial API via Javascript and pass the API key in your requests someone else might use it at your expense.

Also with JavaScript you have to issue your request and then wait for the response before you continue to render your page. With a server side solution querying, error handling, etc. is already done when the browser renders the page; also you might possibly cache the requests to you API to lower your costs and speed up delivery.